# How do we create a new table by importing a huge data from the existing table and avoiding duplicates

Tags: sql

what I am trying to do is create a new table with a huge data avoiding duplicates from the existing table and import the remaining data into the new table. how can i do it?

Comment: this is typically known as a CTAS, "CREATE TABLE AS SELECT".  You write a query that eliminates the duplicates or any other filters you want to apply, and then simply use it in a query like `CREATE TABLE XYZ AS SELECT * FROM ABC`

Comment: You could do a select (your field) INTO dbo.NewTableName  From your query/logic.

Comment: Hey Kurt, Am really new to this!!! can u pls elaborate the statement for me it will be really helpful

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Use SELECT DISTINCT to avoid duplicates. But why do you want another copy of your data? Such copying can lead to data inconsistency. Perhaps you want a _view_ instead?

Comment: hey jarlh, we are using  sql , we have this table employee where we have more than 1000 rows so it have more than 277 null values in certain columns and what we are trying to do is to find the duplicates and remove them and then create a new table only for employees!!! because in the existing table we have more than 277 records that are actually not the employees they have also inserted TV's as employees

Comment: By `we are using sql` do you mean SQL Server? MySQL? Oracle? Something else?

Comment: Also, please always include details / examples. Saying `huge data` is very vague, just tell how many rows there roughly is.

Comment: hey james, am using SQL am sorry for not mentioning properly, i know its inappropriate question!!

Comment: A big table has at least millions of rows. A huge table is even bigger.

Comment: SQL is a _language_, not a dbms. There are dozens of them. Perhaps you mean MS SQL Server?

Comment: yes MS SQL SERVER